# TcxMaskEdit for password field

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2007

I have a EditText declarated as `TcxMaskEdit` for password field and when I write on it the characters show as `*****` but I want that sometimes show the characters, but I don´t find the method for that.

Comment: CodeGear™ C++Builder® 2007 R2 Version 11.0.2902.10471 Copyright © 2007 CodeGea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply using a normal `TEdit` with its `PasswordChar` property set as desired?  You can set it to `'*'` when you want to hide the password, and set it to `0` when you want to show the password.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using a normal `TEdit` with its `PasswordChar` property set as desired?  You can set it to `'*'` when you want to hide the password, and set it to `0` when you want to show the password.

This perfectly works.

Then I add, answering to your doubt (Jjreina)  of showing and not
First, put a SpeedButton by the side of the Edit where the password will be typed
Then in the Events of the SpeedButton
OnMouseDown
(Here you're gonna show the password when you click)

Edit2->PasswordChar=0;

2-> the number of your edit. 
0-> is the default value for showing the characters on the edit

OnMouseUp
(Here you're gonna hide it again when you release the button)

Edit2->PasswordChar='*';

Change the property again to show * instead of the characters

Finally in the property Glyph of the speed button you can put an image (of an eye for example) , this just for the icing on the cake

Hope it works for you, and be useful the answer